# Component has props as function the containsMatchingElement returns false

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

When a component has props as function the containsMatchingElement returns false. When I used debug, I could see the component. So, for testing purpose I removed the function props from the actual code and the test passes. Does anyone know how to make the test pass with the props as function in a component?

```
expect(parent.containsMatchingElement(
  <Child test="foo"setSeverityLevel={jest.fn()}/>
)).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this?

```
expect(parent.containsMatchingElement(
  <Child test="foo" setSeverityLevel={jest.fn}/>
)).toBe(true);
```

You forgot the space between `test="foo"` and `setSeverityLevel={jest.fn()}`.